# wordpress links let me 404 not found

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

### update

When the permalinks is `postname` that would be not found , without `index.php` in url.

[image]

### add .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm the beginner to wordpress. Problem was happened that my website is not found when the permalinks setting is turned to `postname`.

`Home` page is still alive , but click on other links, it couldn't find the right page and show me the 404 not found(not from the wordpress default 404, it's apache2 back)

Remove `index.php` on my url was my first goal . Despite I tried to modified `.htaccess` or restart `apache2` , it didn't work.

Currently , I set back the struct to `index.php/%post_id%/%postname%` and it would work .

How should I do in my terminal or modified something in my wordpress folder?

Comment: What is your `.htaccess` configuration? at which directory?

Comment: What your apache error log say? the log file should be at `/var/log/apache/` directory.

Comment: @hcheung in my wordpress root.

Comment: the `.htaccess` looks correct. Are you saying that the 404 come from apache, not from the WordPress 404 page? Does `LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so` on your apache configuration file uncommented?

Comment: You should also check your VirtualHost conf file to have `AllowOverride All` in the `<Directory>` section for the site in question.

Comment: did you mean your subpages throwing 404 error except homepage?

Comment: Please double check your folder permission.

Comment: @charankumar yes it is .

Comment: @Jagirbahesh should i set the permission for all?

Comment: @RachChen yes, set the permission on the root directory.

Comment: @Jagirbahesh I check my root permission and it's `777` already. Maybe I don't put on the connect to a domain?

Comment: @rach Chen may be your domain is not properly linked . Please check

Comment: Problem is solved, I didn't even know what did I do...